# Is parse local db going to be closed too?

Tags: android, database, parse-platform, parse-server

I use parse and since they have announced they are going to be closed, I want to use Parse local DB. Does Parse shutting down Parse Local Db too on 28th January?

Comment: if you cant read I doubt you would understand any answer here

Answer (score 0):

Parse local DB is a **client** side capability and not server side. Local data store is part of the android/ios Parse **client** SDK's so the answer is **No** it will not be closed only the parse cloud services will be shut down on January 2017(parse.com) so if you use Parse android SDK only for offline scenarios (and not fetching, storing objects to the cloud) then you can still use do it without any problem.

BTW! if you want to still use Parse Android SDK with server side capabilities, i recommend you to have a look on [parse-server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) which the parse.com open source project that you can take and deploy to any cloud provider that support NodeJS runtime (e.g. Google, AWS, Azure etc.). If you don't want to install it on your own and you are looking similar solution to Parse.com you can use [back4app](https://www.back4app.com/) which is a parse-server cloud provider.